# Cannot change hovered link color in nav.menu using Joomla gantry

Tags: css, joomla, menu, hover, nav

(Hi guys!)

I'm creating a small website using Joomla and gantry theme. I'm using a  RokNavMenu, and I want its items to change colors on mouse over.

I've added the changes in my custom .css file accordignly:

```
ul.nav.menu > li:hover a {
color: #8cc414;
}
```

But it doesn't change anything.
I've tried this (just as a test):

```
ul.nav.menu > li:hover a {
color: #8cc414;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
background: #DA0429;
}
```

and I was astounished to see that the font size, weight and background color were taken into account, but the font color itself is still NOT.

All this :hover block is before an :active block as I've seen the order can have an importance.

Can you please help me before I become really nuts?
Thanks a lot,

Stéphanie

p.s. OK thanks to Vitorino it now works - I had to add !important - but why the color should be overriden? Do I have to place this block elsewhere ? 
Here is the entire block concerning nav menus:
Here is the whole block for the nav menus:

```
/* pour les menus RoknavMenu "user menu" */
ul.nav.menu > li a {
    color: #6e6e6e;
    font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: normal;
}

/* en survol */
ul.nav.menu > li:hover a {
    color: #8cc414 !important; /* important a dû être ajouté car sinon overriden */
}

/* élément actif  */
ul.nav.menu > li.active a {
    color: #8cc414;
    font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: normal;
}

/* style de puce devant un élément de menu de navigation user inactif */
ul.nav.menu > li a::before {
    content: " ";
}

/* style de puce devant un élément de menu user ACTIF */
ul.nav.menu > li.active a::before {
    content: "\273F \ ";
}
```

Thx again :)

Comment: I think its getting overwritten try with `!important`

Comment: Hi Vitorino!
Thanks for your ultra-fast answer. That did the trick indeed! So thanks again!
But I thought whatever was in the custom.css was the ultimate style applied... Isn't that so?

Comment: basically styles applied from top to bottom the order of stylesheet also plays a major role with css

Comment: OK, but since the background color , font size etc. are taken into account, why the "color" isn't?
Do I have to place my block elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method is to use id specific overrides by including the `#parentdivid` of the class you're trying to override.

The use of !important is not the recommended method for overrides.

For example:

```
/* en survol */
#rt-roknav ul.nav.menu > li:hover a {
    color: #8cc414;
}
```

For more information on Gantry overrides, there's documentation on their website at:

http://docs.gantry.org/gantry4/tutorials/adding-a-custom-stylesheet

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I didn't want to use !important because I had seen it was EVIL ^^. I tried your method but the color doesn't change on mouseover then.
it seems the only choice is using !important :(